# How it's possible to create a system to navigate between different fragments within a BottomSheetDialogFragment in android java?

Tags: java, android, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I would like to understand if it is possible to replicate this structure:

To explain it better, I would like to understand how to do it:

1. Create a class for managing layouts with listener
2. Integrate listener in main class BottomSheetDialogFragment
3. Manage multiple fragment as Father>Child inside the main Class BottomSheetDialogFragment

I'm expect:

1. XML of different layout
2. Code JAVA

Thanks